# Setting javascript variable from model strings containing Swedish Characters

Tags: javascript, razor, kendo-grid

Newbie type question

I have the following function to set a grids title and fields (dynamic grid)

[image: Grid Title function]

The Model variables can contain Swedish characters

[image]

But when this is all passed to the client , the swedish characters look like this.

[image]

The Grid handles this fine, until it goes to export the Grid to Excel. The columns are fine , but the titles are how the rendered function looks.
[image]

My assumption that this is caused because of the conversion happening when setting from the model variable.

Appreciate any ideas people have :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Razor is a HTML-rendering engine, and is HTML-escaping each `@...` substitution. If you know your content is HTML-safe, you can mark it so:

```
field: "@Html.Raw(d.field)"
```

(and analogously for any other place where you are injecting content in JS strings and not in HTML).

Comment: Awesome!, thank you. I copied what you put and nothing changed.
I was gutted.. till I realized that it's the "d.title" that needed to be changed, not the "d.field".  Of course  I have changed them all now. Thanks again! :)